# Explicit type conversion really necessary?

Tags: c++, casting

Arduino's LiquidCrystal Library defines

```
 virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
```

In their [example](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/780e0a15f63727673ab3a732de268d38768f6cb5/examples/CustomCharacter/CustomCharacter.ino#L129) you'll find a few calls to that function:

```
lcd.write(byte(0)); // when calling lcd.write() '0' must be cast as a byte
lcd.write((byte)1);
lcd.write(4);
```

My C++ is a bit rusty, so I'm not sure why they say it must be cast as a byte?

I mean you wouldn't do something like `byte a = byte(0);` right?

From what I remember and find in the C++ reference this type conversion should happen implicitly so there is no need to explicitly cast it in the function call.

Is this documentation/example just as inconsistent and bad as I think it is? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe there are overloads for the `write` function? In that case, you'd need the cast to pick the correct call. I also notice that the code you linked uses calls like `lcd.write(3);` (no cast) a bit further on.

Comment: always avoid implicit casts where possible, makes your code alot more readable and less error prone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that's due to these 2 overloads in the base class [`Print`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.h#L51):

```
virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
size_t write(const char *str);
```

If called as `write(0)`, the `write(const char *)` overload will be selected as a better candidate (the first requires a narrowing conversion, but 0 *is* a null-pointer).

So to send a `0` byte, you must use an explicit cast to help the compiler choose the right overload: `write((uint8_t)0)`.

---

In addition, you can get a warning "*narrowing conversion, possible loss of data*" if you let a larger type implicitly convert to a smaller one. So it's always a good idea to use an explicit cast to tell the compiler you know what you're doing.

Comment: Maybe I overlooked something, but [`LiquidCrystal`](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/780e0a15f63727673ab3a732de268d38768f6cb5/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp) has only one overload :  `LiquidCrystal::write(uint8_t value)`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it implements the virtual function, but the class [inherits](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/780e0a15f63727673ab3a732de268d38768f6cb5/src/LiquidCrystal.h#L45) from `Print`.